# How to connect to the Remote Database using Connection String in C#.net

Tags: c#, database

every one. I want to connect a remote database using Sql Connection String in C#.net, I am trying it to do, but failed to connect. I am new to C#.net connections to the Database. Can any one pls tell me how to write the Connection String.

Comment: Can you give us the error message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this website for the specific format: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little bit of code that will connect to a dabase called **myDatabase** on a server called **myServer**, query the **myTable** table for the column **myColumn**, and insert the returned data into a list of strings.

While by no means exaustive or perfect, this snippet does show some of the core aspects of working with data in C#.

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = myServerAddress; Initial Catalog = myDataBase; User Id = myUsername; Password = myPassword;");
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
{
  command.Connection = conn;
  command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  command.CommandText = "Select myColumn from myTable";
  using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while (dr.Read())
    {
      results.Add(dr["myColumn"].ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**There is no difference in this regard**. The connection string to connect to remote server database is written same as you write to connect to local database server.

However, only `Data Source` changes.

Below is a sample connection string

```
User ID=dbUserName;Password=dbUserPwd;Initial Catalog=dbName;Data Source=remoteMachine\serverInstanceNameIfAny;
```

But by default sql server is not configured to `Sql Server Authentication`, so you need to enable

- [Sql server authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx)
- Also [Create a Log in user in the database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of examples:

With Integrated Security

```
Server=RemoteMachineName\Intance; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; Integrated Security=true;
```

With username and password

```
Server=RemoteMachineName\Intance; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; UID=Username; PWD=Password;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that in web.config file

```
<configuration>
<ConnectionStrings>
<add name="YourConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=Nameofserver;
InitialCatalog=NameofDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;
UserID=DatabaseUserID;Password=DatabasePassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```